# How do I get Python code to run in RStudio? No Python installed in the system

Tags: python, r, rstudio, translate

I'm working on a research project where the data is stored in a remote Windows desktop. The desktop does not have Python, it only has Rstudio, but  most of the research conducted in this topic was in Python. I want to benchmark already existing implementations, but I can't run the code on the data because there's no Python and this will not change. As far as I understand, tools like `reticulate` still need an underlying Python interpreter in the system to work and I am not allowed to do that.

Has anyone come up with a smart solution that does not involve me manually translating the python code to R? Any R packages that can read python? Any other out-of-the-box ideas on how to get that code to run on the data?

Comment: If you can't install python locally, your best bet would be an online interpreter. Running python code without a python interpreter is not practical. Also, even if you find a miraculous solution, it won't be suitable for benchmarking.

Comment: Two paths: 1. Get the data off the machine and run it on a different machine. (Laptop, VPS, ...) 2. Somehow install Python (install as local user or get portable Python version).

Answer (score 0):

### Can't install Python on Windows? Just Use WinPython

WinPython is a free open-source portable distribution of the Python programming language for Windows 8/10 and scientific and educational usage.

Since it is portable, it is a zero install option. This is probably the best option for you.

https://winpython.github.io/

Once you have WinPython on the machine, if you want to use it with RStudio, you'll need to [configure `reticulate`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html) to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have (1) the remote Windows Desktop that does not have Python and (2) the local computer you work on.

Use the remote Windows Desktop (1) as a git repository, clone that repository on your local machine, make changes to it and run locally using Python, then submit the code to the remote repository again.